# asp.net generating .tmp files

Tags: asp.net, iis

Apparently I did something to break my iis configuration - now every time I hit a modified  aspx file, it makes a file like ve-9D04.tmp in the same folder with the same source.

Presumably the compiler is doing this, but I can't figure out what changed to cause this.

How do I get asp.net's compiler to stop generating these .tmp files all over my site?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a more explicit question? That will help you get results.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic compilation and debug mode cause that, but I believe those files are deleted when the process is done.
If you haven't changed your build, check the web.config files and machine.config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the TEMP folder is not present/accessible anymore by the ASP/IIS process and it therefore stores the temporary files in the same location as the sources?